# find string and replace

Tags: string, find

Hi I have a file like this

> L_00001_mRNA_interferase_MazF
>   ATGGATTATCCAAAACAAAAGGATATTGTCTGGATTGATTTTGACCCTTCTAAAGGCAAA
>   GAGATAAGAAAGCGGAGACCTGCGTTAGTAGTTAGTAAAGATGAATTTAATGAACGTACA
>   GGTTTCTGTTTAGTTTGCCCCATCACATCTACTAAAAGGAACTTTGCAACGTATATTGAA
>   ATAACAGACCCACAGAAAGTAGAAGGGGACGTAGTTACCCATCAATTGCGAGCGGTTGAT
>   TACACCACAAGAAATATCGAAAAAATTGAACAATGTGATATGTTGACGTGGATTGATGTA
>   GTAGAAGTAATCGGAATGTTTATTTAA
>
> L_00002_hypothetical_protein
>   ATGGAAACGGTAGTTAGAAAGATAGGGAATTCAGTAGGAACTATTTTTCCGAAAAGTATT
>   TCACCACAAGTTGGAGAAAAGTTCACTATTCTTAAAGTTGGGGAAGCGTATATATTGAAA
>   CCTAAGAGAGAAGATATTTTTAAAAATGCTGAAGATTGGGTAGGGTTTAGAGAAGCTTTG
>   ACTAATGAAGATAAAGAATGGGACGAGATGAAACTTGAGGGAGGAGAACGCTAG
>
> L_00003_hypothetical_protein
>   ATGACAACGTTTGGAGAAATTCATAGCAATGCAGAAGGTTATAAAAACGATTTTAATGAG
>   TTGAATAAATTAGTATTACGTGTAGCTGAAGAAAAAGCAAAAGGAGAGCCATTAGTAACG
>   TGGTTTCGGTTGCGGAATCGTAGGATTGCACAAGTATTAGACCCAATGAAAGAAGAAGTA
>   GAAAGTAAATCAAAGTACGAAAAAAGAAGAGTAGCAGCAATTAGTAAAAGCTTTTTTCTA
>   CTTAAAAAAGCTTTTAACTTTATTGAAGCAGAACAATTTGAAAAAGCAGAAAAATTAATT

I would like to substitute the header of each sequence with a string.

I have a conversion file like

L_00001_mRNA_interferase_MazF galM,GALM,aldose1-epimerase[EC:5.1.3.3]

L_00002_hypothetical_protein E3.2.1.85,lacG,6-phospho-beta-galactosidase[EC:3.2.1.85]

L_00003_hypothetical_protein PTS-Lac-EIIB,lacE,PTSsystem,lactose-specificIIBcomponent[EC:2.7.1.69]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear as to what platform you're on (Windows, Linux, Mac, ...), what languages you're constrained to, and the exact details of your input files.

On the assumption that you're on Linux, or otherwise have `sed` and `awk` available and a command shell, it could be as simple as (where `$` indicates a Bourne-like shell prompt):

```
$ awk '{print "s/^" $1 "/" $2 "/"}' conversions.txt > conversions.sed
$ sed -f conversions.sed sequences.txt > relabeled.txt
```

This assumes that your first file (with the headings you want changed) is called `sequences.txt` and your second file (the “conversion file”) is called `conversions.txt`. It is further assumed that the “conversion file” contains one record per line with exactly two fields — the original and substitute headers — separated by whitespace (i.e. neither the original header nor the new header contain any spaces) and no blank lines.

In this solution, the first (`awk`) line converts the `conversions.txt` file into a `sed` script, `conversions.sed`; the second (`sed`) line then runs this script on the `sequences.txt` file, producing the `relabeled.txt` file, which may (or may not) be what you're looking for.

Depending on the exact nature of your input files, which isn't clear from your question, this may need a bit of tweaking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the solution works well, you should upvote & accept.